# JPA (and inheritance) how do I get all entities of a given superclass

Tags: java, jpa

Given the following entity definitions:

```
@Entity
class abstract A {
    Collection<A> parents;
}


@Entity
class B extends A {

}


@Entity
class C extends A {

}
```

is it possible to define a method which returns all entities of type B & C having a given parent, **without** having to make two separate calls and then merging the results?

```
Collection<A> getAllByParentId(long id)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
List<A> results = entityManager
                      .createQuery("Select a from A a", A.class)
                      .getResultList();
```

Comment: What is from A a? Why not just from A?

Comment: `a` is just an alias for class `A`. It appears unnecessary.